# SQL Server: convert JSON variable to XML

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, xml

I have a variable which contains a single JSON object like

```
declare @jsonVar nvarchar(max) = N'{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}';
```

I need to convert it to XML and get something like this (or without 'root' at all)

```
<root>
  <key1>value1</key1>
  <key2>value2</key2>
</root>
```

The solution should be universal and should not list JSON keys, since they can vary.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't do it in SQL then. That's not what SQL, the language,  is for

Comment: `(or without 'root' at all)` that wouldn't be valid XML. What are you actually trying to do? Why are you trying to convert between text formats in the *database* ?

Comment: You can use `OPENJSON` to read the JSON string as a table and `FOR XML RAW` to convert query results to XML. `select * from openjson(@jsonvar) for xml raw, elements` will generate XML with elements instead of attributes but the results won't be what you expect. You can't have arbitrary columns in SQL, the language. SQL is strongly typed and even when you use `*`, that's expanded to the actual list of columns at compilation time. Only then is an execution plan generated. If `OPENJSON` generates `key` and `value` columns, that's what will appear in XML too

Comment: For a known JSON structure, a statement like this `SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (key1 varchar(50), key2 varchar(50)) FOR XML PATH ('root')` is an option.

Comment: I wanna tag Yitzhak Khabinsky for this question

Comment: @mike_grinin Why do you want such results? What you ask is a bad idea for several reasons. What happens if the attribute names contain characters that are invalid in element names? A single space or `&` will cause problems and require replacement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one option using `string_agg()` and `OPENJSON()`.   Note this is simple/non-nested approach.

**Example**

```
declare @jsonVar nvarchar(max) = N'{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}';

Select '<root>' + string_agg( concat('<',[key],'>',value,'</',[key],'>'),'' )  + '</root>'
 From  OPENJSON(@jsonVar)
```

**Results**

```
<root>
   <key1>value1</key1>
   <key2>value2</key2>
</root>
```

Comment: This will fail if the attributes and values contain invalid characters eg  spaces or slashes in the keys, angle brackets anywhere

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Correct.  XML is rather particular with attribute names.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to add a running number to the XML element names, i.e.  `<key1>`,  `<key2>`, etc.

Check it out a different more palatable XML structure.

And as @PanagiotisKanavos pointed out, it will protect you from having values that contain invalid characters for the XML element names, eg spaces or slashes in the keys, angle brackets, and the like.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @jsonVar NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM  OPENJSON(@jsonVar)
)
SELECT * 
FROM rs
FOR XML PATH('row'), TYPE, ROOT('root');
```

**Output**

```
<root>
  <row>
    <key>key1</key>
    <value>value1</value>
    <type>1</type>
  </row>
  <row>
    <key>key2</key>
    <value>value2</value>
    <type>1</type>
  </row>
</root>
```

Comment: My first thought as well, but not the desired results.

Comment: Not the desired results but far safer than what the OP asked for. `select * from openjson(@jsonvar) for xml raw, elements,root` There's no need to use a subquery, although `PATH` can help rename the row element